# ODBC query against sysobjects does not return user defined objects

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sysobjects

I'm running the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM sysobjects 
WHERE type = 'P' 
ORDER BY name
```

against several SQL Server 2019 databases using ODBC.

For one of the databases the query refuses to return user defined objects over ODBC. It returns all system procedures and if drop the type it will return all system objects but no user defined tables, views or procedures.

Executing the same query as that user in SSMS will return the user defined objects

I'm using the same SQL Server login/user in all the databases and I have double checked the permissions over and over again. Effective permissions for the user in all databases are:

```
CONNECT
SELECT
VIEW ANY COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY DEFINITION
VIEW ANY COLUMN MASTER KEY DEFINITION
VIEW DATABASE STATE
VIEW DEFINITION
```

The ODBC datasources are all set up the same way.

But obviously I'm missing something - any 2 cents welcome!

Comment: Check sys.database_permissions for any DENYs.

Answer (score 0):

DOH - I lied when I said the ODBC sources were all set up the same. For some reason I missed changing the default database to the one in question in this case. And I managed to miss that several times when I went through and checked.